# Как отсортировать товары Woocomerce через get строку?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Пробую написать фильтр товаров по атрибутам. В get строку передаются параметры ?`filter_emotion=happy`. Как правильно записать в строку 2 и более аргумента для одного атрибута? Что бы можно было отсортировать по множественному выбору.
Хочется сделать как-то так `?filter_emotion=happy+filter_emotion=happy2` или `?filter_emotion=happy+heppy2`

Comment: Установленных правил тут нет. Пишите так, как удобнее вам потом будет разбирать полученную строку.

Comment: Вопрос имеет очень слабое отношение к WordPress и WooCommerce.

Comment: Я хочу воспользоваться встроенными возможностями woocomerce. По умолчанию доступна сортировка товаров, если перейти по ссылке ?filtering=1&filter_emotion=bold . Вопрос звучит как: реально ли использовать встроенный функционал для сортировки что бы передать 2 и более аргумента одного параметра?

Comment: Теперь понятно, посмотрю код WC позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php` есть такая строка

```
$filter_terms = ! empty( $_GET[ 'filter_' . $attribute ] ) ? explode( ',', wc_clean( $_GET[ 'filter_' . $attribute ] ) ) : array();
```

Следовательно, можно передавать несколько значений атрибута, разделенных запятыми.

Для теста созданы 2 товара с атрибутом color:

Фильм №1: color=red, white

Фильм №2: color=white

При обращении к сайту с запросом http://test.kagg.eu/shop/?filter_color=red - выводится Фильм №1

При обращении к сайту с запросом http://test.kagg.eu/shop/?filter_color=white - выводятся Фильм №1 и Фильм №2

При обращении к сайту с запросом http://test.kagg.eu/shop/?filter_color=red,white - выводится товар, у которого присутствуют оба атрибута, т.е. Фильм №1.

**ВЫВОД**

В адресной строке магазина WooCommerce можно указывать перечень атрибутов, разделенных запятыми, например:

`http://site.org/shop/?filter_emotion=happy,happy2`