# Как отсортировать товары Woocomerce по минимальному и максимальному значениям атрибута?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как отсортировать товары Woocomerce, передав через get строку минимальное и максимальное значения атрибута?

Например `shop/?filtering=1&attr-min=10&attr-max=100` по аналогии с фильтром по цене?

Answer (score 0):

Так сделать нельзя. [В этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/638257/220220) на основании анализа кода WooCommerce указано, что можно лишь указать несколько значений атрибутов, разделенных запятыми. Других возможностей при работе через `$_GET` WooCommerce не предоставляет.